# Accessing current logged in user in CakePHP

Tags: logging, cakephp-2.3

I'm accessing to the current user data with this code:

```
$this->loadModel('User');
$this->User->id = AuthComponent::user('id');
$user = $this->User->read();
$this->set('current_user', $user);
```

Everything ok with that, but how can I check if there is no user logged in? Shall I get a `null` value? I didn't find anything about that case.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

According to the [CakePHP Manual (Authentication)](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/components/authentication.html#AuthComponent%3a%3auser):

> If the current user is not logged in or the key doesn't exist, null will be returned.